# Verilog ERROR ** Error: (vlog-13069) (96): near "endmodule":

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I've recently started working in Verilog for a class and have attempted to make a state machine. Please let me know what I am doing wrong as I keep getting errors. It says that it is an error near `endmodule` but doesn't specify. I tried to change things around and add additional ends and things like that at the bottom in case I missed one. It continues to give me an error. I'm sure it's something simple that I am missing. Please help me. I am really confused on why it will not work.

```
module FSM(input KEY0, SW0, SW1, SW2, SW3, SW4,

                        output [6:0] HEX0, HEX1, HEX2, HEX3, output reg [2:0] state,

                        output reg [1:0] Z, output reg [4:0] LED_SW0, LED_SW1, LED_SW2, LED_SW3, LED_SW4);
reg [2:0] nextstate;
localparam start=3'b000, state1=3'b001, state2=3'b011, state3=3'b100;
always @ (posedge KEY0 or posedge SW0)
    if(SW0) begin
        state <=start;
        end
    else
        state <= nextstate;
always @ (*) begin
    nextstate = state;
    Z=2'b0;
    LED_SW0='b0;
    LED_SW1='b0;
    LED_SW2='b0;
    LED_SW3='b0;
    LED_SW4='b0;
    HEX0 = 7'b0;
    HEX1 = 7'b0;
    HEX2 = 7'b0;
    HEX3 = 7'b0;
if(SW0)
    LED_SW0=1;
else
    LED_SW0=0;
if(SW1)
    LED_SW1=1;
else
    LED_SW1=0;
if(SW2)
    LED_SW2=1;
else
    LED_SW2=0;
if(SW3)
    LED_SW3=1;
else
    LED_SW3=0;
if(SW4)
    LED_SW4=1;
else
    LED_SW4=0;
case(state)
start:begin
Z=2'b00;
HEX0[6]=1; HEX0[5]=1; //b
HEX1[6]=1; HEX1[5]=1; HEX1[4]=1; HEX1[3]=1; HEX1[1]=1; //r
HEX2[3]=1; //A
HEX3[2]=1; //g
if(~SW0&&SW1&&~SW2&&~SW3&&~SW4)
nextstate = state1;
else
nextstate = start;
end
state1: begin
Z=2'b00;
HEX0[0]=1; HEX0[3]=1; HEX0[4]=1; HEX0[5]=1; HEX0[6]=1; 
HEX1[6]=1; 
HEX2[0]=1; HEX2[1]=1; HEX2[2]=1; HEX2[4]=1; HEX2[5]=1; HEX2[6]=1; 
HEX3[1]=1; HEX3[4]=1;
if(~SW0&&~SW1&&SW2&&~SW3&&~SW4)
nextstate = state2;
else 
nextstate = state1;
end
state2 : begin
Z=2'b10;
HEX0[2]=1; HEX0[5]=1; 
HEX1[6]=1; 
HEX2[0]=1; HEX2[1]=1; HEX2[2]=1; HEX2[4]=1; HEX2[5]=1; HEX2[6]=1; 
HEX3[1]=1; HEX3[4]=1;
if(~SW0&&~SW1&&~SW2&&~SW3&&SW4)
nextstate = state1;
else if(~SW0&&~SW1&&~SW2&&SW3&&~SW4)
nextstate = state3;
else
nextstate = state2;
end
state3:begin
Z=2'b11;
HEX0[1]=1; HEX0[2]=1; 
HEX1[6]=1; 
HEX2[0]=1; HEX2[1]=1; HEX2[2]=1; HEX2[4]=1; HEX2[5]=1; HEX2[6]=1; 
HEX3[1]=1; HEX3[4]=1;
if(~SW0&&~SW1&&SW2&&~SW3&&~SW4)
nextstate = state1;
else if(~SW0&&~SW1&&~SW2&&~SW3&&SW4)
nextstate = start;
else
nextstate=state3;
end
endcase
endmodule
```

Comment: you are missing `end` for the always block which has `begin`.  would be easier to see if you do right indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're `end`ing the `always` block, I think you are not. And generally re-check all the `end`s for each statement. Also, properly align the contents of your code, in order to better clarify and spot such errors (general advice).

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems in your code

- The `always @ (posedge KEY0 or posedge SW0)` does not have a corresponding `begin` or `end`
- `always @(*)` is not having a corresponding `end` to its `begin`. It should come after the `endcase`

And yes, proper indentation always helps to identify such errors. In general you should always introduce `begin`-`end` from the start (wherever needed) and then fit your code in between.